# Three.js: vertexAttributePointer: no bound ARRAY_BUFFER (after migration to r69)

Tags: javascript, three.js

After migrating from three.js r68 to 69 to get a couple of these errors repeated:

```
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: vertexAttribPointer: no bound ARRAY_BUFFER
[.WebGLRenderingContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 0
```

It appears in the WebGLRenderer in setupVertexAttributes() at this particular line:

```
_gl.vertexAttribPointer( programAttribute, size, _gl.FLOAT, false, 0, startIndex * size * 4 ); // 4 bytes per Float32
```

I use BufferGeometry, but don't know whats wrong. I checked the release notes, but couldn't get a glue. Help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem in my code. I had to adapt my code to reflect the move of the fromGeometry() function from the BufferGeometryUtils class to the BufferGeometry class. So that fixed my issue:

```
var geo = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
geo.fromGeometry(otherGeo);
```

Anyway thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same warnings.

This occurs when you have objects with shadows in your scene that are drawn outside of the camera view. You can test this by;

1. disabling your shadows
2. initially positioning your camera in a position so that it shows all of the scene.

I haven't been able to think of a clean fix, but option 2 worked for me. I haven't tried out the first option, later enabling the shadows.

Comment: thanks chris for your reply. (Unfortunately) my scene has shadows disabled by design and none of my objects has shadow enabled as well. So that seems not the problem in my case.

Comment: Yeah, it seems I was getting a slightly different error, sorry. Could you add the code that seems to trigger the warnings?

Comment: It seems to me that its the render() method of threejs itself, which makes me nervous, as it gives me no indication where to start searching.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in the dev version.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5293